# Moodle - Adding an element to the settings menu

Tags: php, moodle

I'm trying to develop a plugin in `Moodle`. One of the requirements is to add an `element` to the `Settings` Menu, in which I was able to achieve with the help of this guide

> https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins#Adding_an_element_to_the_settings_menu

And this is my code in `local/myplugin/lib.php`

```
<?php 



function local_myplugin_extends_settings_navigation($settingsnav, $context) {
        // question_extend_settings_navigation
    global $CFG, $PAGE;

    // Only add this settings item on non-site course pages.
    if (!$PAGE->course or $PAGE->course->id == 1) {
        return;
    }

    // Only let users with the appropriate capability see this settings item.
    /*if (!has_capability('moodle/backup:backupcourse', context_course::instance($PAGE->course->id))) {
        return;
    }*/

    if ($settingnode = $settingsnav->find('courseadmin', navigation_node::TYPE_COURSE)) {
        $strfoo = get_string('classrecord', 'local_myplugin');
        $url = new moodle_url('/course/classrecord.php', array('id' => $PAGE->course->id));
        $foonode = navigation_node::create(
            $strfoo,
            $url,
            navigation_node::NODETYPE_LEAF,
            'myplugin',
            'myplugin',
            new pix_icon('i/grades', $strfoo)
            );
        if ($PAGE->url->compare($url, URL_MATCH_BASE)) {
            $foonode->make_active();
        }

        $settingnode->add_node($foonode); 

    }
}

?>
```

I allowed the students to see the element "Class Record" in the settings menu

[image: class record element under settings menu]

My concern is that how can I hide/show `Class Record` I added?

Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only certain users to see the link, then create an appropriate capability in local/myplugin/db/[access.php](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Access_API#How_to_define_new_capabilities_in_plugins), e.g. 'local/myplugin:viewclassrecord', defaulting to being assigned to the 'student' role. Then check for it in the function you have defined.

e.g.

```
if (!has_capability('local/myplugin:viewclassrecord', $context)) {
    return;
}
```